# Unknown package, basic errors

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, package, cannot-find-symbol

It seems to be a very simple problem, but i don't get it.
I'm trying to computerize a storage / an inventory with Java EE, JSP and tomcat (i'm french by the way, sorry by advance for language mistakes)

What I tried to do here :

I have an Excel file (.xls) which holds the role of the database.
I read the .xls file and define for every line an Object ("Outil" by translation it's a "Tool") as you can see in "CommandeOutils.java" 
("/WEB-INF/classes/pac/cmd").

```
package pac.cmd;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import pac.bdd.beans.Outil;

/**CommandeOutils.java*/
public class CommandeOutils implements Commande
{
private final String next;

private static FileOutputStream fos;
private static Row              row;
private static Cell             cell;
public static Outil[]           outil;

public CommandeOutils(String next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String execute(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\lomoc\\Desktop\\INVENTAIRE_NOUVEAU_OUTILLAGE.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet("listing");
    int noOfRows = sh.getLastRowNum();
    for (int i = 1; i < noOfRows; i++)
    {
        if (sh.getRow(i) == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        outil[i] = new Outil(sh.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue(), (sh.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue()),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(2).getStringCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(3).getStringCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(4).getStringCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(5).getDateCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(6).getDateCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(7).getBooleanCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(8).getBooleanCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(9).getDateCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(10).getDateCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(11).getStringCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(12).getStringCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(13).getStringCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(14).getStringCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(15).getDateCellValue(),
                sh.getRow(i).getCell(16).getBooleanCellValue(), sh.getRow(i).getCell(17).getBooleanCellValue());
    }

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/outils.jsp" );
    return next;
}
```

}

My "Outil" object is define in "Outil" class ("/WEB-INF/classes/pac/bdd/beans").

```
package pac.bdd.beans;

import java.util.Date;

public class Outil
{
    private String  designation;
    private String  numInterne;
    private String  numSerie;
    private String  marque;
    private String  classement;
    private Date    dateAchat;
    private Date    dateFinDeVie;
    private boolean verifInterne;
    private boolean verifExterne;
    private Date    derniereVerification;
    private Date    prochaineVerification;
    private String  observation;
    private String  utilisateur;
    private String  dateSortie;
    private String  utilisateurPrecedent;
    private Date    dateRetour;
    private boolean conforme;
    private boolean nonConforme;

    public Outil(String designation, String numInterne, String numSerie, String marque,
                 String classement, Date dateAchat, Date dateFinDeVie, boolean verifInterne,
                 boolean verifExterne, Date derniereVerification, Date prochaineVerification,
                 String observation, String utilisateur, String dateSortie, String utilisateurPrecedent,
                 Date dateRetour, boolean conforme, boolean nonConforme)
    {
        this.designation = designation;
        this.numInterne = numInterne;
        this.numSerie = numSerie;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.classement = classement;
        this.dateAchat = dateAchat;
        this.dateFinDeVie = dateFinDeVie;
        this.verifInterne = verifInterne;
        this.verifExterne = verifExterne;
        this.derniereVerification = derniereVerification;
        this.prochaineVerification = prochaineVerification;
        this.observation = observation;
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
        this.dateSortie = dateSortie;
        this.utilisateurPrecedent = utilisateurPrecedent;
        this.dateRetour = dateRetour;
        this.conforme = conforme;
        this.nonConforme = nonConforme;
    }

    /*Hidden Getters & Setters*/
}
```

In "outils.jsp", i just print `for (int i = 0; i < CommandeOutils.outil.length; i++)` in a table with per example for an element `out.println("<li>" + CommandeOutils.outil[i].getDesignation() + "</li>");`

I compile manually, (same result if i recompile with Intellij Idea), and I got this, i already red topics about that problem, i tried many things and don't figure it out, i don't know if it's a compilation problem, a package problem, the folders tree, imports...

```
    C:\Users\lomoc\Cours\S4\JSP\webapps\V4_2\WEB-INF>javac classes\pac\cmd\*.java
classes\pac\cmd\CommandeOutils.java:9: error: package pac.bdd.beans does not exist
import pac.bdd.beans.Outil;
^
classes\pac\cmd\CommandeOutils.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
public static Outil[] outil;
^
symbol:   class Outil
location: class CommandeOutils
classes\pac\cmd\CommandeOutils.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
outil[i] = new Outil(sh.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue(),
(sh.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue()),
^
symbol:   class Outil
location: class CommandeOutils
3 errors
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: check this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706217/3714122` to fix `cannot find symbol` error.

Comment: I'm posting here because i'm in a Java EE context, some rules are defined, the issues are differents in much cases. Here I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

I could see that you are only compiling the java files in `classes\pac\cmd\*.java` folder, this will only compile the files and it will not compile the java files `pac\bdd\beans\` location.

You need to compile the java files `pac\bdd\beans\` location first because your class depends on the other class which is this package later try to compile the java files in `classes\pac\cmd\` location.

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/bNxZ4S/Project_Tree.jpg, the .class are already there, say me if you need more precisions.